# JQuery fade in effect without hiding elements inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, fadein

In this code I am using the fadein effect to append the data. The problem is that everything in wrapper_middle hides and then fades in.. How can I add this effect only to the data appended ?

```
$this.find('.wrapper_middle').hide().append(data).fadeIn(500);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$this.find('.wrapper_middle').append($(data).hide().fadeIn(500));
```

or

```
$(data).hide().fadeIn(500).appendTo( $('.wrapper_middle', $this) );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. i found the answer

Answer (score 1):

Use [appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) to target the elements that are being appended

```
$(data).hide().appendTo($this.find('.wrapper_middle')).fadeIn(500);
```

Comment: OP saying that my solution is not working, Is there any difference between hiding before appending and hiding after appending.? Any ideas on why my solution not working.?

Answer (score 1):

`.append()` will return the object of the `element` to which you appended the `new element`. But `.appendTo()` is opposite to that, It will return the object of the `appended element`. .appendTo() will suit your need.

Try this,

```
$(data).appendTo($this.find('.wrapper_middle')).hide().fadeIn(500);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. but for some reason it didnt append the data at all .. $(data).hide().appendTo($this.find('.wrapper_middle')).fadeIn(500); .. that worked

Comment: I'm confused. This should work. Are you seeing any errors in the console.?